# Is bipartite maximal matching an NP Hard or NP Complete or neither?

Tags: np-complete, bipartite-graphs

Is the bipartite maximal matching problem is NP hard or NP complete or neither? If it's either can someone cite a paper saying so? Also, if its not too trivial to ask, can someone explain NP Hard and NP Complete concepts too?

PS: It is a one- to - many matching

Answer (score 2):

Bipartite maximal matchings can be found in time polynomial to the number of vertices and edges using the [Hopcraft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm).  So it is not an NP-complete problem unless P = NP.

The concepts of NP-hardness and NP-completeness are covered in the Computer Science StackExchange question ["In basic terms, what is the definition of P, NP, NP-Complete, and NP-Hard?"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/in-basic-terms-what-is-the-definition-of-p-np-np-complete-and-np-hard)