# Latin Square and Graph Theory

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, latin-square

How many "$1$" can be selected at most, provided that only one from each row and column of the attached matrix $A$ is selected?(That is, when one "$1$" is selected, no other element can be selected than the row and column where that "$1$" is located.)

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$

Answer: I think $6$ can be chosen.  How can I give this answer in connection with graph theory? I think it has to do with the Latin Square(or Rectangle). But I can't connect and explain.

Please help me. I thought a lot, but I could not establish the relationship completely. Thanks...

Comment: You are correct, the answer is $6$. It is easy to select $6$ ones, and you cannot select $7$ ones, since the only ones in the 3rd and 7th rows are in the same column. However, the question "how does this connect to graph theory" does not have an obvious answer to me, and is I think too vague to be appropriate on this site. If you can reword your question to be more specific, or to explain why you want a connection with graph theory, then maybe you can get a good answer. Otherwise, I will vote to close this.

Comment: Next term, I will prepare a thesis in the field of graph theory. I'm doing some research. My teacher said you can take a look at the relationship between matrices and graphs. I came across this question while working on Latin squares. Logically, I found the answer to 6. But what formula, theorem, etc. of the graph can do this? I can explain with I couldn't find it. Should I use the Latin square or do I have another suggestion? I've been struggling for days. I want help. @MikeEarnest

Comment: I've posted an answer which might help, but if you are looking for help in finding a research direction for the intersection between matrices and graphs, then you are better off getting help from your teacher. I wish you the best in your research.

Comment: I don't see a sound connection with latin squares (or rectangles)   While the definition of latin squares involves having exactly one of each symbol in a row or column of a matrix, for a $7\times 7$ matrix one would have $7$ symbols (not just $0,1$ binary entries).  It would improve your Question to explain how this arose "while working on [l]atin squares."

Comment: Could it be related to max match? I came to the conclusion that it has nothing to do with the Latin square. Let's make a two-set graph by rows and columns and find the maximum match. I think the number of elements in the maximum match will give us the result, I tried it and came to the conclusion of 6. @MikeEarnest

Comment: Could it be related to max match? I came to the conclusion that it has nothing to do with the Latin square. Let's make a two-set graph by rows and columns and find the maximum match. I think the number of elements in the maximum match will give us the result, I tried it and came to the conclusion of 6. @hardmath

Comment: Yes, as @MikeEarnest's Answer describes, this is a maximum bipartite matching problem with two parts of size $7$.  Combinatorial problems typically can be considered in a variety of ways, including this one.  It could treated as a maximum independent set problem on a graph with $22$ vertices as saulspatz described, but efficient algorithms such as [Hopcraft-Karp](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1306646/3111) are available for bipartite matching.

Comment: Thanks @hardmath

Answer (score 1):

An $m\times n$ binary matrix can represent a biparite graph on $A\sqcup B$, where $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n$, and a one at entry $(i,j)$ means the $i^{th}$ vertex of $A$ is joined to the $j^{th}$ vertex of $B$. Then, a selection of ones in pairwise different rows and columns corresponds to a  *matching* in that bipartite graph. A matching is a subset of edges where no two edges in the subset have a common endpoint. Therefore, asking the largest number of ones in pairwise different rows and columns is equivalent to asking what is the size of the *maximum matching* in that graph.

There is a lot of research in the field of maximum matchings, especially for bipartite graphs. There are several algorithms which compute the maximum matching reasonable of a bipartite graph quickly, described in the Wikipedia page for maximum matchings. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching

Comment: Thank you @Mike Earnest

Comment: Is there a formula for the size of the max match? I think the size of a maximum matching set with $n$ elements is $n-1$. Is it correct? @Mike Earnest

Comment: There's an algorithm to compute the size of the maximum matching, but no "formula." The size of the largest possible matching for a the type of $n\times n$ matrix you posted is $n$, which is attained when the matrix is all ones, for example.

Comment: +1 As the Wikipedia article on [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Of_a_bipartite_graph) observes, this {0,1} matrix is sometimes called a *biadjacency matrix*.